# Is it a good practice to invoke APIs within AWS Lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, api, aws-lambda, step

We need to orchestrate DB calls with API calls and expose the orchestration as an API. I understand that I can expose an express (sync) Step Function as an API using AWS API Gateway and make the Step Function to orchestrate API GW invokes and DB calls (for e.g. DynamoDB). Another approach could be to develop a lambda that invokes the DB calls and APIs. Which approach is best and why? Thanks.

Comment: API Gateway > Lambda > DynamoDB -- what is the actual problem?

Comment: I agree with Ermiya. Step Functions would be overkill for basic CRUD operations